# C# LINQ - What can I do here to improve performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm doing some heavy filtering on a collection (which is nothing more than an encapsulated list of entries of "datalines").
I need to 'consolidate' these lines on 3 fields (Date (string), Route (string) and ConsolidationCode (string)).

Extracting the 3 Distinct Lists works fast. I'm more worried about the triple foreach...
I'd say that a normal "complete _DealerCaseSetComplete contains 5000 entries.
The Dates would be around 5, the Routes would be around 100 and the Consolidations 350-500.

**I have written following method. It does exactly what I want it to do, but is very slow in calculationtime. 
Perhaps you people could guide me towards a faster code execution.**

*If you require any other code (which is really plain actually, please ask.*

```
private void FillDataGridView()
    {
        //
        _LocalGridControl.Invoke(CreateDataGrid);

        //Filter by Date
        List<string> Dates = _DealerCaseSetComplete.Data.Select(rec => rec.DateAdded).Distinct().ToList();

        //Filter by Route
        List<string> Routes = _DealerCaseSetComplete.Data.Select(rec => rec.Route).Distinct().ToList();

        //Filter by Consolidation
        List<string> Consolidations = _DealerCaseSetComplete.Data.Select(rec => rec.DealerConsolidationCode).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach(string d in Dates)
        {
            foreach(string r in Routes)
            {
                foreach(string c in Consolidations)
                {
                    List<DealerCaseLine> Filter = _DealerCaseSetComplete.Data.Where(rec => rec.DateAdded == d &&
                                                                                    rec.Route == r &&
                                                                                    rec.DealerConsolidationCode == c).ToList();
                    if(Filter.Count > 0)
                        _LocalGridControl.Invoke(AddLineToDataGrid, Filter);
                }
            }
        }
        _LocalGridControl.Invoke(SortDataGrid);
    }
```

Comment: What does your filter actually do?  It doesn't look like it's actually filtering anything out...

Comment: it looks like you can filter as you go along so your not having to include routes etc that are not valid.

Comment: @Moho My Filter object is a filtered extract of my complete list.

Comment: you're getting all distinct values then iterating over each possible combination of these distinct values - that would return all items in the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need grouping by three fields:

```
var filters = from r in _DealerCaseSetComplete.Data
              group r by new { 
                   r.DateAdded, 
                   r.Route, 
                   r.DealerConsolidationCode 
              } into g              
              select g.ToList();

foreach(List<DealerCaseLine> filter in filters)
    _LocalGridControl.Invoke(AddLineToDataGrid, filter);
```

Your code iterates all data **three times** to get distinct fields. Then it iterates all data **for all combinations** of distinct fields (when you do filtering with where clause). With grouping by this three fields you will iterate data only **once**. Each resulting group will have at least one item, so you don't need to check if there is any items in group, before invoking filter.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Speed increase is massive!
I did not know that the group by into clause returned a new IEnuerable<List<DealerCaseLine>>, instead of List<DealerCaseLine>; which is perfect in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get every distinct combination of Dates, Routes and Consolidations.

Your current code is slow because it is, I think, O(n^4).  You have three nested loops, the body of which is a linear search.

You can get much better performance by using the overload of Distinct that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

```
var Consolidated = 
  _DealerCaseSetComplete.Data.Select(rec => rec).
  Distinct(new DealerCaseComparer());
```

The class `DealerCaseComparer` would be implemented much as in the above MSDN link.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'm trying to get a list of unique or distinct values, based on these 3 values.

Comment: I have marked the other one as answer because it suited the situation better. I did some research about IEqualityComparer and I can definately see its use.
Thanks for sharing!